# How can I get the 'id' in `get_context_data` from CBV?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm kinda confused since I had to override get_context_data method in order to use a template context.

urls.py

```
re_path(
    r"^post/(?P<id>\d+)/$",PostView.as_view(template_name="pages/post.html"),
    name="post",
),
```

views.py

```
class PostView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'djangoapp/pages/post.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['dataC'] = get_object_or_404(Content, Título_id="2")
        return context
```

Comment: Did you tried to print out the `kwargs` in `get_context_data`?

Comment: I just did that and I'm not getting reverse match, idk if I'm doing it correctly tho.

Comment: If you get an error you need to show it. It's not coming from the code you've posted here, in any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it from `self.kwargs['pk'].`

Comment: So... I'd be something like: pk=self.kwargs.get("pk")? If not, can you please explain? I'm still not getting reverse match.

Comment: if you have pk in the url you will get it else pk will be blank